# How to schedule run shell script that opens Firefox

Tags: x11, cron, firefox

I have the shell script which opens Firefox and launches macros in it (I use a Firefox add-on called Imacros to create macros). The content of my shell script named `house.sh` is like that:

```
firefox imacros://run/?m=house.iim
```

And I created a scheduled job via `crontab -e` to run that script hourly every day:

```
47 * * * * /home/meerim/bin/house.sh
```

But nothing happened (Firefox didn't open). Then I tried this:

```
47 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/meerim/bin/house.sh
```

But it didn't solve the problem.
So how should I fix it?
My `house.sh` script works properly when I run it from terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this to run by putting in `house.sh`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and running `xhost +` on your interface. Once that works you can restrict who is allowed to connect (using `xhost` again), but once things stop working you'll know how permissive you have to be.

This will not work if you are not logged in. I there run firefox from a python script started with crontab, and the actual interface opens in a Xvnc screen independent of whether I am logged in or not (and it doesn't clobber my UI once it starts running).

Comment: I've added export DiSPLAY=:0.0 to house.sh and it worked! And now I'm trying to fulfill ur second recommendation about xhost. I ran xhost + and it said that clients can connect from any host.  Now I should restrict allowance but  how I will do it, I mean I should put my username or the value that I get from running hostname command in the code: xhost - name. By the way, I use Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: If it already works, you don't need to use `xhost +` at all, that was to make sure you could connect and were not restricted by X. After logging out and back in this will reset to normal values (or run `xhost -`)

Comment: This is the 21st century. I cannot condone a recommendation to run `xhost +`.

Comment: I added a new job to my crontab exactly the same as previous one like that 58 * * * * /home/meerim/bin/santehnik.sh. But it doesn't work. Only the first one which is house.sh. Although I put in santehnik.sh "export DISPLAY=:0.0" too. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Stranger difficult to tell without seeing the scripts. Did you put it at the beginning? Are you calling Firefox again? Maybe better to put up a new question showing both scripts.

Comment: Well, the content of santehnik.sh is the same as house.sh: export DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox imacros://run/?m=santehnik.iim. And I put that job in the same crontab -e after house.sh like following: 58 * * * * /home/meerim/bin/santehnik.sh. And interesting is that only house.sh is working but the second job is not.

Comment: Did you run `chmod +x ` on the new script?

Comment: That's where I made a mistake. Thank you very much, @Anthon